# Sistema de Gestão de Tempo C++

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho que desenvolver um sistema de gestão de tempo pra cadeira de Estrutura de Dados na faculdade, mas estou me batendo para fazer funcionar. O que é pedido é o seguinte:

"Desenvolva um sistema de gestão de tempo. Este sistema deve armazenar a
descrição e o tempo de atividades, não sendo possível extrapolar o limite de 20 atividades
no sistema e que seja capaz de apresentar o somatório do tempo das atividades. Para
desenvolver este sistema, implemente uma classe Atividade, composta por dois atributos,
descricao e tempo, em que, descricao é uma string e tempo é um objeto do tipo Tempo,
composto pelos atributos hora e minuto, ambos inteiros"

O que consegui desenvolver até agora foi isso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class valorMinuto
{
    int line;
    string file;

public:
    valorMinuto(int line, string file)
    {
        this->line = line;
        this->file = file;
    }
    string messange()
    {
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Erro na linha " << this->line << " no arquivo " << this->file << endl;
        oss << "valor de minuto menor que 0 ou maior que 59" << endl;
        return oss.str();
    }
};

class limiteExcedido
{
    int line;
    string file;

public:
    limiteExcedido(int line, string file)
    {
        this->line = line;
        this->file = file;
    }
    string messange()
    {
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Erro na linha " << this->line << " no arquivo " << this->file << endl;
        oss << "limite de armazenamento excedido!" << endl;
        return oss.str();
    }
};

class Tempo
{
public:
    int hora, minuto;
    Tempo();
    Tempo operator+ (const Tempo&) const;
    void setHora(int h);
    void setMinuto(int m);

};

Tempo::Tempo()
{
}

void Tempo::setHora(int h)
{
        hora = h;
}

void Tempo::setMinuto(int m)
{
    try {
        minuto = m;
        if (minuto < 0 || minuto > 60)
        {
            throw(valorMinuto(__LINE__, __FILE__));
        }
    }
    catch (valorMinuto exception)
    {
        cout << "Excecao: " << exception.messange() << endl;
    }
}

Tempo Tempo:: operator+ (const Tempo& param) const
{
    Tempo temp;
    temp.hora = hora + param.hora;
    temp.minuto = minuto + param.minuto;

    temp.hora += temp.minuto / 60;
    temp.minuto %= 60;

    return temp;
}



class Atividade
{
public:
    Tempo tempo;
    string descricao;
    Atividade();
    ~Atividade();
    int cont;
    void setHora(int x);
    void setMinuto(int x);
    int getHora();
    int getMinuto();
    Tempo getTempo();
    void setDescricao(string x);
    string getDescricao();
};

Atividade::Atividade()
{
}


Atividade::~Atividade()
{
}

void Atividade::setHora(int x)
{
    tempo.setHora(x);
}

void Atividade::setMinuto(int x)
{
    tempo.setMinuto(x);
}

int Atividade::getHora()
{
    return tempo.hora;
}

int Atividade::getMinuto()
{
    return tempo.minuto;
}

void Atividade::setDescricao(string x)
{
    descricao = x;
}

string Atividade::getDescricao()
{
    return descricao;
}

Tempo Atividade::getTempo()
{
    return tempo;
}


class App
{
    vector<Atividade> atividades;
public:
    App() {
    }

    ~App() {

    }

    void addAtividade(Atividade value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this->atividades.size >= 20) {
                throw limiteExcedido(__LINE__, __FILE__);
            }
        }
        catch (limiteExcedido exception)
        {
            cout << "Excecao: " << exception.messange() << endl;
        }
        this->atividades.push_back(value);
    }

    Tempo soma() {
        Tempo s;
        for (vector<Atividade>::iterator it = this->atividades.begin(); it != this->atividades.end(); it++)
        {
            s = s + it->getTempo();
        }
        return s;
    }
};


int main()
{

    App app;
    app.addAtividade(*new Atividade);
    app.addAtividade(*new Atividade);
    app.addAtividade(*new Atividade);


    Tempo r = app.soma();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Mas não sei direito como usar app.addAtividade() para adicionar uma nova atividade, nem como adicionar o tempo de cada uma. Tô bem perdido no desenvolvimento. Se qualquer um conseguir me dar uma ajuda ou algum insight, apreciaria muito! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - No método "addAtividade", você esqueceu de usar "( )" na parte em que chama a função que o retorna o tamanho do vetor. O certo é "atividades.size()" ou o compilador vai entender que você tá usando um ponteiro pra função e não invocando uma função. Além disso, você tá capturando uma exceção que é lançada dentro do mesmo método e isso não faz sentido(você poderia ter usado std::cout logo de uma vez ou capturado a exceção no método main()). E não passe classes de exceção por valor, o certo aqui é passar por referência, ou você não poderá usar polimorfismo dentro do bloco catch, além do mais, o compilador irá criar um novo objeto temporário e o resultado pode ser diferente do que você espera.

```
void addAtividade(const Atividade& value)
{
    if (this->atividades.size() >= 20) {
        throw limiteExcedido(__LINE__, __FILE__);
    }

    this->atividades.push_back(value);
}
```

2 - Na função main, você tá instanciando o objeto Atividade com new e está errado. Operador new retorna um ponteiro pra um objeto, não um objeto em si. Você deve instanciar como um objeto na pilha e deixar que o seu std::vector inclua ele na memória. O certo seria assim:

```
int main()
{

    try
    {
        App app;
        app.addAtividade(Atividade());
        app.addAtividade(Atividade());
        app.addAtividade(Atividade());

        Tempo r = app.soma();
    }
    catch (limiteExcedido& exception)
    {
        cout << "Excecao: " << exception.messange() << endl;
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bah, ajudou muito!! Só ainda me resta uma dúvida: como eu faço para acessar cada uma das atividades criadas no app.addAtividade(Atividade()) afim de setar um tempo para cada uma?

Comment: No std::vector, basta acessar como se fosse um array comum. atividades[0] atividades[1], atividades[2], etc.